# Example where $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x^2)$ exists but $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ does not.

Tags: calculus

Can somebody give me an example where $$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x^2)$$ exists but $$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$$ does not?

Comment: $f(x)=\sqrt x$.

Comment: sign function is the best example.

Comment: Many have pointed out very simple examples. In this question what one needs to see is that when we are thinking of $f(x^{2})$ we are only considering the values of $f$ for non-negative values of the argument. But in $f(x)$ we are considering both negative and positive values of the argument. Hence a counter example is created if we let $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}f(x)$ exist and at the same time let $\lim_{x \to 0^{-}}f(x)$ not exist. All the examples given follow this.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh : At least one example has both one-sided limits of $f$ exist.

Comment: @EricTowers: you are right! But I can't edit my comment now.

Answer (score 21):

Yes.  Let $f(x) = 1$ for $x<0$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x \geq 0$.  $f(x^2) = 0$ so the limit exists.  $f(x)$ is has a jumpt discontinuity at zero (the limit from the left is $1$ but the limit from the right is zero) so the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 6):

For example

$$f(x):=\frac{|x|}x\implies\;\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\;\text{does not exist (check one sided limits), but}$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x^2)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2}{x^2}=1\;\;\text{does exist}\;\ldots$$

The first part above is nothing else but the proof of the well known fact that the absolute value function isn't differentiable at zero.

Comment: This is hardly any different from what what posted and upvoted 6hs ago.

Comment: Didn't even see it, @PedroTamaroff, yet after checking I trust you're able to see it is way a different example of a function than the one given there, and in this case it is a rather familiar function...

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x) = \chi_{[0,\infty)}(x)$, the characteristic function of the interval $[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \sqrt{x}$  would be a good choice because the domain of f(x) is not a punctured neighbourhood of zero. Whereas it is trivial that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} {x}$$ exists

Comment: If you take sqrt x then also the limit exists